# SQL Server 2008 database timeout after delete

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm running the following statement, it is working locally with SQL Server 2008, however, there is SQL Server 2008 Express on the development server, and after the sql statement runs, I am unable to do SELECT statements on the table in which I deleted the record.  Both databases were created with the same table creation scripts.

```
"DELETE FROM [dbo].[tblMiddayMover] WITH (ROWLOCK)  WHERE [idMiddayMover] = @IdMiddayMover"
```

What reasons would this statement ever cause the database to hang.

After executing that statement, the following SELECT statement causes an error.

```
"SELECT * FROM [dbo].[tblMiddayMover] WHERE [fldActive] = 1"
```

I get the following error:

Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I can do select statements on any other table with no issues.

I ran the command that was suggested, here is the output.
[alt text http://softwaredesignexcellence.com/capture.PNG](http://softwaredesignexcellence.com/capture.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved.  Actually, I was using a code generator to do the stored procs and Data Layer, which created a transaction layer around all the database calls.  However, the issue was that it targeted .NET 3.5 and the server was set up to use .NET 2.0.  It wasn't a database issue as much as it was an incompatibly issue with the version of .NET on the server.

Comment: I couldn't change the version of the .NET Framework, because it only allowed up to .NET 2.0, but I managed to include the 3.5 specific assemblies that were required in the BIN folder of the project, and it ran fine.  It was a while ago, so I don't remember what DLLs had to be included, i just Changed the "Copy Local" to True on the properties of the DLLs until it worked, so they were published with the project.

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that you have created a transaction around your statement which is still open and has not been committed or rolled back.

I suggest opening another window before the second query times out and execute the procedure "sp_who2".  This has a column which will definitively tell you if a query is being blocked by another query (it's called "BlkBy") which is running concurrently.

Comment: 57    SUSPENDED                      scottrends ELEET-SBS2008 56    scottrends INSERT           15 0 03/27 13:11:46 .Net SqlClient Data Provider                   57    0

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/07/19/sql-server-get-last-running-query-based-on-spid/  That will tell you what query last ran on SPID 56.  You probably have a transaction open in SPID 56.  Find out why the transaction has not committed or rolled back, and you will probably have solved your problem.